# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fasttext'

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, fasttext

I have tried installing `fasttext` through conda using two channels:

`conda install -c conda-forge fasttext`

and

`conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 fasttext`

as per (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/fasttext).

I am using the following command to import: `import fasttext`
However, the import fails with the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 import fasttext
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fasttext'

However, tried to import it in an older fashion `import fastText`, which failed.

Have tried it on `python` and `python3`, both of which fail.

I want to avoid installing it using `pip` and manage the packages using `conda`.

`conda list` shows that `fasttext` being installed. The output of which is shown below:

`fasttext                  0.2.0                hfc679d8_1    conda-forge/label/cf201901`

The output of `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)` is as below:

`['', '/<dir>/<dir>/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip', '/<dir>/<dir>/anaconda3/lib/python3.7', '/<dir>/<dir>/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/<dir>/<dir>/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages']`

Comment: fasttext =/= fastText, so no surprise that failed there. Is there any kind of virtual environment or anything that could be impacting this?

Comment: What platform you're on? Could you provide the result of `which -a python` on *nix, `where python` from `cmd.exe` on Windows? Could you provide the full `conda list` output as well?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question, I have tried importing in both the ways `import fasttext` and `import fastText`, both of which fails.

Comment: `which - a python` yields: `/<dir>/<dir>/anaconda3/bin/python
/usr/bin/python`

Comment: First, just do `conda install -c conda-forge fasttext`, not both. The additional subchannels (labels) that existing on Anaconda Cloud are usually for very specialized purposes (e.g., alternative build toolchains). Second, from your activated environment, please get the output of `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)` and add it to your question.

Comment: @merv, I have updated the question with whatever you have said.

Answer (score 6):

I used [fastText](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html) in this way:

```
!git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText.git
!cd fastText
!pip install fastText
import fasttext.util
fasttext.util.download_model('en', if_exists='ignore')  # English
model = fasttext.load_model('cc.en.300.bin')
```

Note 1: Pay attention to uppercase letters.

Note 2: [Here](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/language-identification.html#list-of-supported-languages) is the list of supported languages.